# My Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS freezes entire system occasionally except for mouse. What to do?

Tags: freeze, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

System freezes and even seconds in clock stop. Keyboard no responds only mouse pointer moves but no left nor right click. How to fix?

Comment: What is your hardware specs? try to update your BIOS

Comment: How to recome from freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen always after an specif event, or out of the blue?

Have you tried restarting the window manager lightdm from a tty?

- hit Ctrl + Alt + F2
- login
- type: sudo service lightdm restart

This will close your apps though.